# Get faster row Count with Where Clause in Sql Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL query to get the count of matching input. When I run the query, it takes 28 seconds to get the count. Is there any faster way to get the matching count than simply using `COUNT(Key)`.

**Query**

```
select 
    count(id) 
from 
    bibcontents
where 
    tagno = '245' 
    and normvalue like 'china %'
    or normvalue like '% china%'
```

Any help to this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not a single LIKE '% china %'

Comment: I don't see how COUNT() could be the problem, how big is your table?

Comment: Right now, The table having 35 lakhs of records. This query count is for autocomplete with pagination.

Comment: @Mihai: `'% china %'` wont work when china is the starting word of a string.

Comment: The Likes with or are quite expensive.Maybe try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803783/sql-server-index-any-improvement-for-like-queries