# WHERE clause on NULLable columns, containg LIKE, keep index usage

Tags: sql-server, null, indexing, sql-like

For a table with a column ColA as VARCHAR(x), how should I rewrite this condition

```
ColA LIKE @param + '%'
```

taking into account that:

- 1/ ColA is NULLable.
- 2/ @param could be NULL
- 3/ There is an index on ColA, and it should be used for all searches
- 4/ Avoid sp_executesql as this is part of much larger stored proc

I was thinking at:

```
ISNULL(ColA, '') LIKE (CASE WHEN @param IS NULL THEN '%' ELSE @param + '%' END)
```

but this will not make use of index defined on ColA.

Comment: If @param is null, should rows where colA is null be returned? Ie should nulls be considered "equal"?

Comment: @Bohemian: yes, NULLs should be considered "equal"

Comment: "There is an index on ColA, and it should be used for all searches" - well, it won't be. A `LIKE` condition with a leading wildcard can *not* use an index.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Oh, you are right. I'll rephrase this: Title + '%'

Answer (score 1):

Split into two conditions:

```
...
WHERE ((@param is null AND ColA is null)
  OR (@param IS NOT NULL AND ColA LIKE @param + '%'))
```

But OR often kills index usage, so if that doesn't work, try further split into two queries:

```
...
WHERE @param is null
AND ColA is null
UNION
...
WHERE @param IS NOT NULL
AND ColA LIKE @param + '%'
```

But

Comment: I think the second condition `@param IS NOT NULL` is needless. In case of `@param=NULL` we get `ColA LIKE NULL` and it's always FALSE.

Comment: @valex *logically* it might be unnecessary, but *performance* may be far greater with it in because the entire LIKE search can be avoided when param is null. With the additional test, it may execute the like anyway (depending on optimizer)

Comment: I Agree it depends on optimizer.

Comment: What is I have 2 columns, ColA, ColB, with 2 indexes?

Comment: Do you have a param for each, or do they share the same param?

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
WHERE ((@param is NULL) and (ColA is NULL)) OR (ColA LIKE '%' + @param + '%')
```

But if you use `LIKE '%' + @param + '%'` index can't be used (if it isn't FULL-TEXT index):

[- SQL Server Index - Any improvement for LIKE queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803783/sql-server-index-any-improvement-for-like-queries)

[- Index usage by %Like% operator – Query Tuning](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2009/11/30/index-usage-by-like-operator-query-tuning.aspx)

Comment: It will return ColA=NULL only if @param is NULL.

Comment: No it won't it will return every row when param is null

Comment: @Bohemian Seems I've misunderstood that question. I changed the answer.