# Adding index for faster search

Tags: sql-server, select, indexing

I cannot remember how to add an index for faster lookup from the table.
I have a primary key, but I want to have an index for faster lookup of rows by the Component code.
For a faster reading of:

```sql
select * from prices where ComponentCode like '%something%'
```

Look at the two last lines of the script

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Prices] (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ComponentCode   varchar(255),
    Description VARCHAR(255),
    PriceUnit   float,
    Price   float
);
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Prices]
ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Prices]
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_Prices ON [dbo].[Prices] (ComponentCode);
GO
```

Comment: Do you really require a leading wildcard? (`'%something%'`) If so a B tree index will be of limited use (just gives you something a bit narrower to scan). For non prefix searches you need to be looking at full text indexing

Comment: If this is about MS SQL Server, which seems so, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803783/sql-server-index-any-improvement-for-like-queries

Comment: A table can only have one `CLUSTERED` index. That roughly defines how the table data is physically organized. Change `CLUSTERED` to `NONCLUSTERED` or drop the keyword entirely since non-clustered is the default.

Comment: I would suggest not using the float datatype for prices. You should instead a precise numeric type like numeric.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of an index as a sorted tree that holds the values of the column and pointers back to the rows they come from. This improves the speed of queries since it's faster to search a sorted tree than an unsorted list.

However, in this query, you're looking for a substring in the **middle** of the value (since you have a `%` wildcard at the beginning of the right operand). In this case, the fact that the values of `ComponentCode` are stored in a sorted index won't help you, and the database just ignores the index.

Comment: The index will have ComponentCode and ID, so is narrower to scan, and may cover some queries.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft OP's query doesn't use `id`, so the index shouldn't cover it. What am I missing?

Comment: Even with a wildcard search, an index scan followed by a key lookup can be much faster that a table scan, because the amount of data read to scan the index is typically much smaller. (This is actually one of the cases where storing a large amount of "covering" columns is detrimental.)

Comment: Nonclustered indexes always contain the "row locator", which here is the clustered index key ID.  Non-unique non-clustered indexes are stored as unique indexes with the missing clustered index key columns added to the nonclustered index keys to make it unique.  For unique nonclustered indexes the clustered index key columns are stored as "included columns" on the leaf pages.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft that I get. But the query OP is asking about is `select * from prices where ComponentCode like '%something%'`. The `id` isn't in the **query**, so having it implicitly in the index shouldn't help either.

Comment: The only way to know if an index speeds up a query is to make tests and measure...

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Prices_ComponentCode ON [dbo].[Prices] (ComponentCode);
```

But as others have said, it's not a silver bullet for wildcard searches.